# Django's REST framework custom exception handling doesn't seem to work as advertised

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

July 2019 - Using latest Django/DRF:

in `myproj/my_api_app/public_views.py` I have:

```
def custom_exception_handler(exc, context):

    # Call REST framework's default exception handler first,
    # to get the standard error response.
    response = exception_handler(exc, context)

    # Now add the HTTP status code to the response.
    if response is not None:
        response.data['status_code'] = response.status_code

    return response
```

in `myproj/myproj/settings.py` I have: (Yes, two times *myproj/myproj*)

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    # Use Django's standard `django.contrib.auth` permissions,
    # or allow read-only access for unauthenticated users.
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.DjangoModelPermissionsOrAnonReadOnly'
    ],
    'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_CLASSES': (
            'rest_framework.throttling.ScopedRateThrottle',
        ),
    'DEFAULT_THROTTLE_RATES': {
        'public_get': '30/minute',
        'user_get': '60/minute'
    },
    'EXCEPTION_HANDLER': 'myproj.my_api_app.public_views.custom_exception_handler'
}
```

I try to hit a non-existing endpoint on purpose and I am still getting the default 404 message. I have `DEBUG=False` in settings.

I have tried every permutation of the "Path" for the `EXCEPTION_HANDLER`. Nothing works. The `EXCEPTION_HANDLER` is simply ignored. `custom_exception_handler` is never called.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rest-framework exception view doesn't work for invalid route. Try to send an invalid request to an API route to see it in action.

Comment: yep. figured that out. I'm using the handle404 in that particular case now and it works well. Thanks.